# Call By Reference C when sending pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Look At these three simple codes

1.

```
void call_by_reference(int *y) {
(*y) = 20;
printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d after adding 10.\n", *y);
}

int main() {
int *b=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
//*b = 10;
call_by_reference(b);
printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", *b);
return 0;
}
```

2.

```
void call_by_reference(int *y) {
y=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
(*y) = 20;
printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d after adding 10.\n", *y);
}

int main() {
int *b= NULL;
call_by_reference(b);
printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", *b);
return 0;
}
```

3.

```
void call_by_reference(int **y) {
(**y) = 20;
printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d after adding 10.\n", **y);
}

int main() {
int *b=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*b = 10;
call_by_reference(&b);
printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", *b);
return 0;
}
```

The outputs in each case are

1.

```
Inside call_by_reference y = 20 after adding 10.
b = 20 after function call_by_reference.
```

2.

```
Inside call_by_reference y = 20 after adding 10.
```

and then segmentation fault popup due to printf line in main

3.

```
Inside call_by_reference y = 20 after adding 10.
b = 20 after function call_by_reference.
```

So I understand the output of codes 2 and 3.

Since C has nothing like call by reference

So in 2, since i have a NULL Pointer in main, in get a segment error when trying to access it,

In 3 i m passing pointer to pointer so its like call by reference

But Why does in code 1 the value of b in main get updated..???

UPDATE::
If you think code 1 is working normally then why is code 2 showing error,
The calling procedures of both codes are same i think.

Comment: If you ask questions about C programming, please don't any other unrelated language tags, even if the languages seems to be similar.

Comment: *"Why does in code 1 the value of b in main get updated..???"* Because you update it in the function `call_by_reference(int *y)` with `y` being the address of `*b`.

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised that (3) even compiled. When I take the code for 3 to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c99_online.php and run it it segfaults immediately. If you change the call to `call_by_reference` to `call_by_reference(&b);` it works fine, of course.

Comment: Thanks Bob for pointing it out, it actually was a typo i have updated the question code

Comment: Your code is never "adding 10". Misleading texts don't help.

Comment: The third case is *very* wrong as pointed out by @BobJarvis. And it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Some programmer dude, considering whats pointed out by bob, as i said it was a typo the actual code has
    `call_by_reference(&b);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the first case works because it's *emulating* pass by reference there. You pass a pointer to some allocated memory to the function, dereference the pointer inside the function and writes to the allocated memory, which is then used in the output after the function.

You don't even have to allocate dynamically in the first case:

```
int main() {
    int b;
    call_by_reference(&b);
    printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", *b);
    return 0;
}
```

would have worked just as fine, and is the "normal" way of handling it.

---

In the first case inside the `call_by_reference` function you have something like this:

```
+-------------+
| b from main | --------------\
+-------------+                \     +-------------------------+
                                >--> | memory for a single int |
+--------------------------+   /     +-------------------------+
| y from call_by_reference | -/
+--------------------------+
```

You have two pointer variables, but both point to the same memory.

In the second case you ***initially*** have

```
+-------------+
| b from main | --------------\
+-------------+                \     +------+
                                >--> | NULL |
+--------------------------+   /     +------+
| y from call_by_reference | -/
+--------------------------+
```

It is very similar to the first case, but then you do

```
y=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and now you instead have this:

```
+-------------+     +------+
| b from main | --> | NULL |
+-------------+     +------+

+--------------------------+     +--------------------+
| y from call_by_reference | --> | memory for one int |
+--------------------------+     +--------------------+
```

The two pointers are no longer the same.

Comment: In that case why is there a error in code 2,the calling procedure is same its just i am allocating memory in call** function instead of main

Comment: @user2984602 Because the *pointer itself* is passed by value. When in the function you have two pointers, `b` from the `main` function and `y` in the `call_by_reference` function. Initially both are pointing to the same memory (`NULL` in this case) then you make `y` in the `call_by_reference` function point somewhere else, the variable `b` in the `main` function is not modified and is still `NULL`.

Comment: I know i don't have to allocate memory, dynamically.But the whole point was to ask a problem using a simplified code.

Comment: Thanx man, I think I understood my problem.
So is there never a need to use code 3 , considering we don't want to return the updated pointer

Comment: @user2984602 Case three *is* useful, but just not they way it is currently written. As you now understand (I hope) you can emulate pass by reference by using pointers. Now how do one emulate pass by reference for a pointer? By passing a pointer to the pointer of course (as you do now in the updated code). That means you can allocate memory and assign to the original pointer variable much like you do in the first code example. So in the function you could do e.g. `*y = malloc(sizeof(int))`

Answer (score 0):

> In code (2), you're passing the pointer 'b' by value which is NULL and in the called function, you're making it to point to a different memory location. So printf in called function will work just fine. But your pointer 'b' in main() is not modified and point to NULL and that's why you're getting the error in code 2.
>   Howerver, you can modify your code and need to pass the address of the pointer 'b' to make it work fine.

```
void call_by_reference(int **y) {
*y=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
(**y) = 20;
printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d after adding 10.\n", **y);
}

int main() 
{
    int *b = NULL;
    call_by_reference(&b);
    printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", *b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In all three cases, `y` and `b` are different objects in memory - any changes you make to `y` won't affect `b`.

In the first case, you assign a value to `b` in `main` using `malloc` (***always*** check the result of a `malloc` call before attempting to use the pointer). You pass this pointer value to `call_by_reference`, which writes to `*y`, updating the value of the thing both `y` and `b` point to.  `main` then prints the value of the thing `b` points to.  Visually, you have something like this:

```
  +---+                          +---+
b |   | -----+-----> heap memory |   | accessed through *b and *y
  +---+      |                   +---+
             |
  +---+      |
y |   | -----+
  +---+
```

Put another way,

```
 b ==  y
*b == *y
```

In the second case, you assign `NULL` to `b` in `main`, and pass that null pointer value to `call_by_reference`, which immediately assigns a new pointer value to `y`.  It updates the thing `y` points to and returns.  *This has no effect on `b`*, which is still `NULL`.  Thus, your code crashes when you try to dereference `b` in the `printf` call.  Visually, you have this:

```
  +---+
b |   | ---|||
  +---+

  +---+                          +---+
y |   | -----------> heap memory |   | accessed through *y only
  +---+                          +---+
```

Put another way,

```
 b == NULL
*b == undefined
```

It also creates a memory leak, since you lose the reference to the allocated memory when the function returns.

In this third case you assign a value to `b`, then pass a *pointer to `b`* to `call_by_reference`, which writes to `**y`, updating the thing `b` points to.

```
  +---+                            +---+
b |   | -------------> heap memory |   | accessed through *b and **y
  +---+                            +---+
    ^
    |
  +---+
y |   |
  +---+
```

Put another way,

```
&b ==   y
 b ==  *y
*b == **y
```

I've used this example elsewhere, but I think it's worth using again.  Normally, we fake call by reference in C something like this:

```
void foo( T *ptr ) // for any type T
{
  *ptr = new_value(); // write a new value to var through *ptr
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;

  foo( &var ); // foo writes a new value to var
}
```

If you replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, you get

```
void foo( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value( ); // write a new value to var through *ptr
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *var;

  foo( &var ); // foo writes a new value to var (not the thing var
}              // points to!)
```

The semantics are the same; we've just changed the types.